# Testing function using jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a function which looks like this:

```js
getPhoneComp() {
    if (this.props.contactDetails.countPhone === 1)
      return (<PhoneComp contactDetails={this.props.contactDetails.phoneSet[0]} contactId={this.props.contactDetails.contactId} errorHandler={this.props.errorHandler} updateMobileNo={this.props.updateMobileNo} />);
    else if (this.props.contactDetails.countPhone === 2) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className={classes.sceESpace}><PhoneComp contactDetails={this.props.contactDetails.phoneSet[0]} contactId={this.props.contactDetails.contactId} errorHandler={this.props.errorHandler} updateMobileNo={this.props.updateMobileNo} /></div>
          <div className={classes.sceESpace}><PhoneComp contactDetails={this.props.contactDetails.phoneSet[1]} contactId={this.props.contactDetails.contactId} errorHandler={this.props.errorHandler} updateMobileNo={this.props.updateMobileNo} /></div>
        </div>
      );

    } else if (this.props.contactDetails.countPhone === 3) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className={classes.sceESpace}><PhoneComp contactDetails={this.props.contactDetails.phoneSet[0]} contactId={this.props.contactDetails.contactId} errorHandler={this.props.errorHandler} updateMobileNo={this.props.updateMobileNo} /></div>
          <div className={classes.sceESpace}><PhoneComp contactDetails={this.props.contactDetails.phoneSet[1]} contactId={this.props.contactDetails.contactId} errorHandler={this.props.errorHandler} updateMobileNo={this.props.updateMobileNo} /></div>
          <div className={classes.sceESpace}><PhoneComp contactDetails={this.props.contactDetails.phoneSet[2]} contactId={this.props.contactDetails.contactId} errorHandler={this.props.errorHandler} updateMobileNo={this.props.updateMobileNo} /></div>
        </div>
      );

    }
    else if (this.props.contactDetails.countPhone === 0) {
      return (
        <div />
      );
    }
  }
```

Then in my render function, I am calling the function as shown below:

```js
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.getPhoneComp()}
      </div>

    );
  }
```

So, currently I am writing a test case for this component as shown below:

```js
 it('renders the Phone component', () => {
      let contactDetailsState={contactDetails:{
        webId:'', 
        contactId:'', 
        isContactPresent:true,
        firstName:'',
        lastName:'',
        middleName:'',
        customerSet:[{customerNumber:'1379',
        customerName:'K F I INCORPORATED',
        serviceAccountCount:2,
        customerContactRelationshipType:'Z00001',
        notificationEmailIndex:'E1',
        customerStatus:'',
        notificationVoiceIndex:'P2',
        customerType:'S',
        notificationPhoneIndex:'P1',
        contactId:'0104489742',
        notificationEmail:'xx1212@a.com',
        notificationVoice:'4564564564',
        notificationSms:'5656565566'}],
        emailSet:[{notificationEmail:'xx1212@a.com',
        notificationEmailIndex:'E1'},
        {notificationEmail:'xx1@a.com',notificationEmailIndex:'E2'}],
        emailSetWithNoAlert:[{notificationEmail:'xx1212@a.com',notificationEmailIndex:'E1'},
        {notificationEmail:'xx1@a.com',notificationEmailIndex:'E2'},
        {notificationEmail:'No email alerts',notificationEmailIndex:'NaN'}],
        phoneSet:[{notificationPhone:'5656565566',notificationPhoneIndex:'P1',
        notificationPhoneType:'M'},{notificationPhone:'4564564564',
        notificationPhoneIndex:'P2',notificationPhoneType:'L'}],phoneSetWithNoAlert
        :[{notificationPhone:'5656565566',notificationPhoneIndex:'P1',
        notificationPhoneType:'M'},{notificationPhone:'4564564564',
        notificationPhoneIndex:'P2',notificationPhoneType:'L'},
        {notificationPhone:'No Phone Alerts',notificationPhoneIndex:'NaN',
        notificationPhoneType:'L'},{notificationPhone:'No Text Alerts',
        notificationPhoneIndex:'NaN',notificationPhoneType:'M'}],
        mobileSet:[{notificationPhone:'5656565566',notificationPhoneIndex:'P1',notificationPhoneType:'M',contactId:'0104489742'}],
        isMobilePresent:true,countEmail:2,countPhone:2,countMobile:1,totalphoneCount:2,
        enrollCustomer:['1379'],suffix:'Jr.',prefix:'Mr.'}};


      let errorHandlerFn=jest.fn();
      let updateMobileNoFn=jest.fn();
      let getPhoneCompFn=jest.fn();
      let phoneComponent = mount(<PhoneContainer contactDetails={contactDetailsState} errorHandler={errorHandlerFn} updateMobileNo={updateMobileNoFn} getPhoneComp={getPhoneCompFn} />);
      expect(getPhoneCompFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

So, I am trying to run the function, but while running this test, I get the below error:

```js
Expected mock function to have been called.
```

in 
`expect(getPhoneCompFn).toHaveBeenCalled();` line in the test. So, how do I test if the function is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getPhoneComp` is not a prop but a method. Since it's prototype method, it can be mocked on class prototype:

```
getPhoneCompFn=jest.spyOn(PhoneContainer.prototype, 'getPhoneComp')
.mockImplementation(() => {});

let phoneComponent = mount(<PhoneContainer ... />);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.Now the error is gone and I can see my function's coverage %age has increased, but the coverage for statements,branch and lines has decreased and is below 50% now, Previously when I was using `expect(getPhoneCompFn).toHaveBeenCalled();` , I could see the coverage for the other 3 was increased and that of functions was 0% and also I was getting the mentioned error.Why is this happening? I mean I don't even have any other lines to be tested in my render function, it just calls the `getPhoneComp()` method.

Comment: Likely because real `getPhoneComp` is never called because it's stubbed. I assume this is unit test. In unit tests, you stub/mock everything but tested unit. You need to test real `getPhoneComp` in another test. It's preferable to use `shallow` for that.

Comment: ohh, okay. Thanks for the help, will write a new test for the function then.

Comment: I have tried writing a test case for my function separately, but its still not increasing the coverage.I have posted a separate question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428619/how-to-write-test-cases-for-a-function-using-jest-and-enzyme . Can you please have a look at it once.