# How to write test cases for a function using jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a react function which renders a component according to the value of props being passed. The function looks as shown below:

```
 getPhoneComp() {
    if (this.props.contactDetails.countPhone === 1)
      return (<PhoneComp contactDetails={this.props.contactDetails.phoneSet[0]} contactId={this.props.contactDetails.contactId} errorHandler={this.props.errorHandler} updateMobileNo={this.props.updateMobileNo} />);
    else if (this.props.contactDetails.countPhone === 2) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className={classes.sceESpace}><PhoneComp contactDetails={this.props.contactDetails.phoneSet[0]} contactId={this.props.contactDetails.contactId} errorHandler={this.props.errorHandler} updateMobileNo={this.props.updateMobileNo} /></div>
          <div className={classes.sceESpace}><PhoneComp contactDetails={this.props.contactDetails.phoneSet[1]} contactId={this.props.contactDetails.contactId} errorHandler={this.props.errorHandler} updateMobileNo={this.props.updateMobileNo} /></div>
        </div>
      );

    } else if (this.props.contactDetails.countPhone === 3) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className={classes.sceESpace}><PhoneComp contactDetails={this.props.contactDetails.phoneSet[0]} contactId={this.props.contactDetails.contactId} errorHandler={this.props.errorHandler} updateMobileNo={this.props.updateMobileNo} /></div>
          <div className={classes.sceESpace}><PhoneComp contactDetails={this.props.contactDetails.phoneSet[1]} contactId={this.props.contactDetails.contactId} errorHandler={this.props.errorHandler} updateMobileNo={this.props.updateMobileNo} /></div>
          <div className={classes.sceESpace}><PhoneComp contactDetails={this.props.contactDetails.phoneSet[2]} contactId={this.props.contactDetails.contactId} errorHandler={this.props.errorHandler} updateMobileNo={this.props.updateMobileNo} /></div>
        </div>
      );

    }
    else if (this.props.contactDetails.countPhone === 0) {
      return (
        <div />
      );
    }
  }
```

And this function is called inside my render function as shown below:

```
  render() {
    app.logger.getLogger().info("props" + JSON.stringify(this.props));
    return (
      <div>
        {this.getPhoneComp()}
      </div>

    );
  }
```

Now, I am trying to write a test case for this function, but I am not able to figure out how to proceed.I wrote the below test case and it's not throwing any error, but the coverage is still the same.My test looks like this:

```
   let phoneComp = shallow(<PhoneContainer contactDetails={contactDetailsState} errorHandler={errorHandlerFn} updateMobileNo={updateMobileNoFn} />);
    phoneComp.instance().getPhoneComp();
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: The answer is correct. Of course, you need to test getPhoneComp thoroughly (with all `this.props.contactDetails.countPhone` conditions) to get full coverage for this method. If you have problems with coverage after doing that, consider checking what lines lack coverage.

Comment: @estus, so in my case I have to check `this.props.contactDetails.countPhone`, so I am not able to figure out how to change the value of the props and check.Also, the answer uses the spyOn function which I have already used earlier as you mentioned in the previous answer, so how to set the value of `this.props.contactDetails.countPhone` to test the function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a spy and an expect statement:

```
  let node = shallow(<PhoneContainer ... />);

  const getPhoneCompSpy = jest.spyOn(node.instance(), 'phoneComp');

  expect(getPhoneCompSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

You can find more details about spys [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have already used the spyOn menthod, So I have doubt in how to set the `this.props.contactDetails.countPhone` value to test the function? Can you please just give me a rough idea on updating the props in the test.

Comment: Sure, this is how you would update your props before you define your spy `node.setProps({contactDetails: {countPhone: 'foobar'}});
        };
        node.update();`

Answer (score 0):

In the way, Fabian have explained to you, you are only checking if the method is being called and nothing else. The logic inside it, like checking the `countPhone` and rendering the `PhoneComp` accordingly, aren't under tests.

IMHO, this is not a good approach at all. You are creating a very fragile test. If you do a minor refactor like rename the method, would break your tests.

In your tests, you have to check what's is actually being rendered at the end and nothing else.

One way to do that is using the `find` and checking the length for the result.

For example:

```
let phoneComp = shallow(<PhoneContainer contactDetails={contactDetailsState};
expect(phoneComp.find(PhoneComp)).toHaveLength(1); // or 2 or 3 regarding the case
```

In this way, you are actually testing the output of the function.

Comment: A fragile test is a good test, in fact. It's better to get a red test when you don't expect it to break rather than get a green test when you expect it to break.

Comment: Of course you can also check for what's actually rendered in the end. Which is a valid approach. However, as I understand the question it was especially wanted to test that this very specific method is called. The procedure I described is a generic approach to test methods, no matter if they return jsx or anything else.

Comment: Hey Fabian, sorry if I offended you. I just tried to give another perspective about how to test.